# Openess about the Pope's children in the Borgias

Tags: historical-accuracy, the-borgias

In the series The Borgias there is a large degree of transparency about the fact that Pope Alexander VI has four children. This is taken to the point where he can marry off said children to political figureheads so as to gain power. Their mother was a Spanish Courtesan so they get no social standing from her.

Is it historially correct that the Pope is so open about his children? Even in the series how is it justified for him to be so open?

I do understand that he did historically aknowledge his children. However there are different levels of acknowledgement. I am asking how he could do so and did he do so to such an extent as portrayed in the series. How could he survive as pope while being so open about his children, to the point where they talk to them as their father infront of most everybody and he offers them in marraige as his children?

Comment: Not sure why this is getting downvoted.  He's asking if the show is historically accurate or not.  Seems on topic, to me.

Comment: @Steve-O Because there's zero research. From the first lines of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pope_Alexander_VI : "He is one of the most controversial of the Renaissance popes, partly because he acknowledged fathering several children by his mistresses." Part of the page is especially about this topic: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pope_Alexander_VI#Mistresses_and_family .

Comment: "I am asking how he could do so" He was the pope, one of the most important people in the world, God's envoy on earth.

Comment: Yes but the Pope was meant to be celibate....

Comment: I guess that's where the above mentioned controversy comes from. I live in a Catholic country and there is a [rector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rector_(ecclesiastical)) in one of the villages in my region, who is being open about having a mistress in a different village. Is such openness normal? No, that's why it's controversial.  I guess it was the same with Alexander, only in a completely different scale.